# What is the recommended way of transferring Sol via a PDA after using SetAuthority?

Tags: pda, authority, signer

I'm currently working on a fundraising program which involves just transacting Sol.

In the first image, I have set fundraiser_config as the authority over the token_vault
[image]

In the second image, I'm transferring Sol from the token_vault to the fundraiser_sol_token_account
[image]

In the third image, I'm writing the test for fundraiser_withdrawal (ie second image ). However, the error is saying that it is an `unknown signer`.
[image]

Please let me know what I have missed out as I have been stuck on this for a while.
Thank you!

Comment: Please use code snippets rather than images

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two accounts for fundraiserWithdrawal in your typescript code: fundraiser and token vault. Add them.

For the rust code, here's example code of me doing something similar, transferring spl-tokens from a token vault with a PDA as its authority:

```
let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
    from: funds_pot.to_account_info(),
    to: destination_account.to_account_info(),
    authority: campaign.to_account_info(),
};

let campaign_seeds = &[
    b"campaign".as_ref(),
    fundstarter.key.as_ref(),
    &[campaign.bump],
];

let signer = &[&campaign_seeds[..]];

let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(token_program.to_account_info(), transfer_instruction)
    .with_signer(signer);
anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount_to_withdraw)?;
```

Here `campaign` is a PDA whose seeds are used as signer for the instruction because it's the authority of the `funds_pot` token account.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for pointing that out! I have added in those 2 accounts but its throwing another error.. However, after thinking about it, since I'm setting vault_authority as pda over the token_vault, would it make more sense for the pda to sign this instruction instead? Given that I'm still getting the error message of `unknown signer`

Comment: The `authority` in the accounts struct for the Transfer instruction has to be the authority of the `from` account(In this case `token_vault`). If it's a PDA then your signer argument should be gotten from whatever its seeds are.

Comment: oooh.. okok. So what I did was added in this piece of code in CreateCampaign struct               

`#[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"vault", fundraiser_config.key().as_ref()],
        bump, 
        payer = fundraiser,
        token::mint = sol_mint,
        token::authority = token_vault
  )]
  pub token_vault: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>, `

Comment: Would doing the above means that fundraiser_config is now the authority of the token_vault ?

Comment: After having added the seeds in, I went on to follow the example you gave above by providing the seeds in to to do the transfer of tokens from token_vault . However, in my test script, it still throws an error saying the `signer` is unknown

Comment: Is it alright if you could take a look at my repo to see what's missing ? It will be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a few weeks and I really do not know what's wrong.   Here is the link to my repo -->    [link](https://github.com/bubu59/MobiusProtocolPL/blob/first/programs/MobiusProtocolPL/src/lib.rs)

Comment: The code in the link is incomplete and vastly different from what's above. I'm voting to close this question because its lacks clarity and isn't specific. Raise a new question that properly specifies the parameters of your problem, or drop me a private message.

Comment: Apologies!! I created a new branch and did not updated the latest changes made !!! 
Here is the new link : [link] (https://github.com/0xSavant/MobiusProtocolPL/tree/restart)

Comment: alright, the problem is solved...